# How to copy entire container?

Tags: docker, containers, devops

I run container on one of the 3 machines(which is dynamically picked up by pipeline) and there I'm facing issue with server startup and to analyze the failure I need another person's help but considering his availability I cannot say when he will be available.

And also I cannot keep occupied that host machine on which container is running as other members on team need it.

Also next time, when developer is available, I'll have to trigger build and take it to that stage where I can show issue to developer, but again that will take time.

In this case, is there any way, I can stop that container and take entire copy of it and next time when needed run it so I'll have container in a state which is needed and also this is less time consuming.

Comment: The app inside the container should log errors. Collecting logs and forwarding them to your dev should be enough.

Comment: An interesting read about *experimental* `docker checkpoint`: https://technology.amis.nl/2018/04/08/first-steps-with-docker-checkpoint-to-create-and-restore-snapshots-of-running-containers/

Comment: Do you know what triggers the error?  Can you `docker run` the same version of the same image, and cause the problem?  Send _that_ description to the developer who's debugging things, and they can turn it into a test case that can get run automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Docker image based on an existing container with `docker commit`, such as:

```
docker commit my-container image-from-my-container
# return an image SHA
```

You can then run a container based on your commited image (matching your container state when it was commited)

```
docker run [OPTIONS] image-from-my-container
```

If you also need to export your image to another machine (as another team member may need the original machine), you can either:

- Push the image to a distant registry with `docker image push` and run it from another machine
- Export your image to a TAR file with `docker image save image-from-my-container > saved-image.tar`, download the archive to another machine, then load it with `docker image load -i saved-image.tar`

Comment: You should almost never use `docker commit`.  In this specific circumstance, it generates an image and that would answer the extremely specific use case in the question; even so, I can't tell you how the process got into this state, so I can't really use the committed image to write a good test case that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes using the image generated from container may not help solve the issue as there may be lots of other factors involved, but it does answer the question as to how "copy" a container. At least using the created image one may put aside issues coming from the container itself and start looking elsewhere